# maven release:perform with Perforce does not create target/checkout directory

Tags: maven, perforce, maven-release-plugin

I can not make the maven-release plugin work with Perforce. The release:prepare seems to work correctly: a Perforce label is created and it contains the correct files. Yet when I run release:perform it fails because the target/checkout directory is empty.

I've done some experiments. If I only sync to my pom.xml and then run
    mvn scm:checkout
then my other files are checked out into the P4 root directory just as if I had done a
    p4 sync ...
Yet Maven outputs
    [INFO] Checkout working directory: /home/chris/perforce/pips/target/checkout
    [INFO] sync -f //depot/pips/...
Maven thinks it's checking out the target/checkout but it is not. I dug into the P4Maven code a little bit and noticed this in P4Executor.java

```
public String getRepoPath(P4ScmProviderRepository repo, File basedir) {
    // Handles a case where executing release:prepare on a module with an
    // invalid SCM location. The release.properties contains the invalid URL
    // for checkout during release:perform and the basedir is not the module
    // root. So, the trailing target/checkout directory must be removed.
    if (basedir.toString().replace('\\', '/').endsWith("/target/checkout")) {
        String dir = basedir.toString();
        basedir = new File(dir.substring(0, dir.length()
                - "/target/checkout".length()));
        if (getLogger().isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Fixing checkout URL: " + basedir);
        }
    }
```

This code is pretty clear. P4Maven won't check things out to target/checkout. If you tell it to checkout to target/checkout it will simply remove the "target/checkout" and checkout to the root directory. This is consistent with what I see being done. I also see the "Fixing checkout URL" message when I run release:perform

How then do people work around this?

Below is my pom.xml. I am using 
  Perforce Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2014.2/935585 (2014/09/16). p4d is running locally. Authentication is disabled and I don't need a password.
  Nexus 2.10.0-02 running locally. 
  Ubuntu Linux. 
  Maven 3.2.3
  java 1.7.0_55

Thanks.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.ap
ache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.icap</groupId>
  <artifactId>pips</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>pips</name>

  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <scm>
     <connection>scm:p4:192.168.1.8:1666://depot/pips</connection>
     <developerConnection>scm:p4:192.168.1.8:1666://depot/pips</developerConnection>
  </scm>

  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.perforce</groupId>
            <artifactId>p4maven</artifactId>
            <version>[2011,2012)</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
          <username>chelck</username>
          <includes>**</includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <dependencies>
          <!-- P4Maven -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.perforce</groupId>
            <artifactId>p4maven</artifactId>
            <version>[2011,2012)</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
          <username>chelck</username>
          <includes>**</includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
     <id>deployment</id>
     <name>Internal Releases</name>
     <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
     <id>deployment</id>
     <name>Internal Releases</name>
     <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have struggled for several days on perforce / maven / release integration and finally got it working. Here are my findings, they might help you and others with similar issues.

1. **Do not use the perforce plugin as described on perforce.com** (http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r11.1/manuals/p4maven/index.html). Although it is the first link to come out of a search on google, my understanding is that this plugin is outdated.

In your  configuration, if you refer to `scm:p4:...` you are using the com.perforce plugin. Instead, use org.apache.maven.scm/maven-scm-provider-perforce which uses `scm:perforce:...` syntax. Your `<scm>` should look like this:

```
<properties>
  <p4path>//perforce-path/toyour/project</p4path>
</properties>

<scm>
  <connection>scm:perforce:yourp4server:1666:${p4path}</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:perforce:yourp4server:1666:${p4path}</developerConnection>
  <url>perforce:yourp4server:1666:${p4path}</url>
</scm>
```

The newer plugin does not require username/password, it will use your active P4 credentials.

I am using maven 3.2.5 and did not have to specify any plugin dependency. The built-in scm recognized the `:perforce:` scm and downloaded maven-scm-provider-perforce 1.9.2 which is the latest as of this writing. You can make sure you are using an up to date plugin by deleting the maven-scm-provider-perforce folder in .m2\repository\org\apache\maven\scm and then doing a `mvn scm:status` - it will download the missing plugin and you can see which one it picked.

Here is my maven-release-plugin definition:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </plugin>
```

I do not have a `maven-scm-plugin` definition in my pom (I used the default settiings from the superpom).

2. Test on a non-module project.

You should be able to do the following without error:
 - `mvn scm:status` to check that your scm setup is working correctly
 - `mvn release:prepare`
 - `mvn release:perform`

If you get errors, rollback (`mvn release:rollback`), make sure everything is back to normal, and rerun with `mvn -X` to get more details.

In my case, a non-modular project worked without much trouble.

3. Test on the parent of a reactor project.

There are a few things that were not obvious to me at first and that I found out:

- **When the  is defined in the parent pom, the child module name gets appended to the path for the child module**. If your child is not physically under the parent (in my case, it was beside), you need to redefine a  configuration in the child pom. In my case, I was using a property (p4path above), simply changing its value was not enough. This was counter-intuitive since the parent pom is normally just a "include", and I expected the parent definitions to be "copy-pasted" in the child module, but in this particular case, it is modified to include the module name at the end of the scm path when it is copy-pasted. [*More on modules that do not sit under the parent directory below*]
- **A temporary client spec is created by the perforce scm plugin**. This was also counter intuitive, I expected the scm plugin to use my current client-spec. Instead, it will create a new one on the fly, and populate it with the path you provided only and name it `username-hostname-MavenSCM-localpath`.  I was initially surprised by that and tried to change it so it would use by client-spec by customizing the `maven.scm.perforce.clientspec.name` property, this behaviour was actually correct. With this temporary client-spec, the plugin can limit the lookup for changes, the submit and tagging to this directory. It also makes it easy to track what was done by this plugin in the perforce history.
- **Creation of the temporary client spec will fail if the modules are not under the parent directory**. As I described above, my modules were sitting beside the parent.  My `<module>` tag in the parent pom referred to them using `<module>../mymodule</module>` which worked fine in eclipse for everything else. The scm perforce plugin includes modules in the client spec by appending the path to the module to the path of the parent. Since Maven resolves the ../ to an absolute path, the client spec ends up containing something like this: `//perforce-path/toyour/project/C:\Path\To\Your\Project/mymodule/` and the client spec fails. I could not find a work around for this issue other than moving my modules under their parent. Since the client spec was invalid, I had no file being checked-out under target/checkout.  You will get the content of your generated client spec on the console by using `mvn -X` when invoking `release:perform`.

**Moral of the story**: You want to make sure that all your modules sit under their parent directory. When you do this, everything becomes simple and magical: you can leave the  declaration in your parent pom and the module path gets magically appended for the module scm paths. You can refer to your modules using `<module>mymodule</module>` which gets correctly appended in the client-spec. Tagging of the parent in perforce ends up also tagging the modules since they are contained within.